# Can I set delegate for input textfield in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cordova, textinput, uitextfielddelegate

I'm developing and application on iOS using PhoneGap. In the HTML content of `UIWebView`, there is an input textfield `<input />`.

My question is can I know the actions of this `<input />` textfield such as `textFieldDidEndEditing:`? Or can I set delegate for this `<input />` textfield. If possible, please show me how. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can get onchange event of input on HTML in UIWebView

`<input type="text" onchange="changeEvent(this)" id="myInput">`

`<script>`
`function changeEvent(ele) {`

`alert(ele.value);`

`}`
`</script>`

Comment: I want AppDelegate to listen and handle the event, not HTML itself.